# ASP.NET how to return a string instead of returning the page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here's the asp.net page which I want to get the response

---

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        B2.Text = Request.QueryString["webget"];
    }
}
```

---

Use this code to send the request in Form

---

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string UrlString = "http://localhost:10694/Default.aspx?webget=more";
    HttpWebRequest req = HttpWebRequest.Create(UrlString) as HttpWebRequest;
    req.Method = "GET";
    string result = "";
    try
    {
        using (HttpWebResponse response = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                result = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        label1.Text = "error";
    }
    label1.Text = result;
}
```

---

This code will download and display the Default.aspx
But if I want to return a string from ASP.NET,rather than downloading the page

How to do that in ASP.NET?

Comment: This is web forms code not MVC (please remove tag)

Comment: Try Response.Write("your string");

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean "Response.Write" function?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525585%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

If you want to return a string in response, try this:
In the page, write:

```
string rtnString = "yourStringHere";
Response.Write(rtnString);
Response.End();
```